# How to pre-cache a workbox NavigationRoute NetworkFirst request?

Tags: workbox

I'm using a NetworkFirst strategy for a NavigationRoute in my workbox-based service worker, so that navigation requests will be served cached responses while the user is offline.

```js
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    new workbox.routing.NavigationRoute(
        new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
            cacheName: 'static-pages',
        }),
    ),
);
```

When I navigate to a page, the navigation request gets cached, and then I can visit it again while offline. So far so good.

However, I need to pre-cache the PWA start URL, so if the user installs the PWA from any page, goes offline, and tries to open it, the PWA start URL is cached and available. In fact, this will be a requirement for the installability prompt as of Chrome 91.

```js
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('static-pages').then(cache => {
            const startUrl = 'https://my-pwa-start-url...';
            return cache.add(startUrl);
        })
    );
});
```

The issue here is that the request for `startUrl` is not a `navigation` request, so even though it gets cached in the `static-pages` cache, it is not used when navigating to the start URL.

I tried manually constructing a navigation request, e.g.

```js
const startUrlRequest = new Request(startUrl, { mode: 'navigate' });
return cache.add(startUrlRequest);
```

But then I get this error:

`TypeError: Failed to construct 'Request': Cannot construct a Request with a RequestInit whose mode member is set as 'navigate'.`

Is there any way to pre-cache a NavigationRequest without actually navigating to the page?

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach that you're attempting—calling `cache.add(startUrl)`—should be fine, although I would recommend doing that in your `install` handler, not `activate`.

In general, there's no need to manually construct a navigation request and pass that to `cache.add()`, and as you've discovered, you *can't* actually construct one without throwing an exception.

The only thing "special" about navigation requests and cached responses is that a redirected response [can't be used](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=669363) to satisfy a navigation request, so just make sure that the URL you're caching doesn't result in a 30x redirect.

So, my guess is that your cache is being properly pre-populated, but there's a cache miss in your `NetworkFirst` strategy. One possible explanation is the presence of query parameters in the URL that you explicitly cached, and a mismatch of those parameters in the URL that's being requested during navigation. You should be able to confirm that by using Chrome's DevTools to inspect the cache and the network traffic. If that's indeed the issue, you could tell Workbox to ignore the query parameters when it tries to find a matching cache entry by passing in the `ignoreSearch` match option:

```
new workbox.strategies.NetworkFirst({
  cacheName: 'static-pages',
  matchOptions: {
    ignoreSearch: true,
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this! It turns out the issue is that have `Vary: User-Agent` response header.
I created two identical pages, one that varies on `User-Agent` and one that doesn't, pre-cached them both, and can only visit the one that does not vary on `User-Agent` when offline.
Not entirely sure why this would break the NetworkFirst cache entry, but it does. @Jeff Posnick, if you have insight into this I'd love to hear it

Comment: Ah, so you can add `ignoreVary: true` to `matchOptions` if you want to ignore that. It's not ignored by default. One recent improvement has been to at least warn folks about this in the DevTools web interface: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1186049